# How to write RESTful web services client based on curl

Tags: java, rest, curl

I need to write a RESTful web service client for Delphix.I am new to delphix and RESTful webservices.How can I write a client based on the below curl.

Create Delphix API Session

> $ curl -s -X POST -k --data @-
>   http://delphix-server/resources/json/delphix/session \
>       -c ~/cookies.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" <

```
   Delphix Login
```

$ curl -s -X POST -k --data @- http://delphix-server/resources/json/delphix/login \

> ```
> -b ~/cookies.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" <<EOF {
> "type": "LoginRequest",
> "username": "delphix_username",
> "password": "delphix_password" } EOF
> ```

please help

Comment: what did you try already? where are you stuck?

Comment: Evgeny Lebedev I know how to write a RESTful client to consume the service.But I am not getting how to write a client for Delphix.Delphix Web service API provides the curl commands for every operation.

Answer (score 1):

Just use decomposition for curl commands. For example as we see [Authentication](https://docs.delphix.com/display/DOCS31/API+Cookbook%3A+Authentication) requres two steps:

**1. create session:**

POST request to `http://delphix-server/resources/json/delphix/session` with JSON-data:

```
{
    "type": "APISession",
    "version": {
        "type": "APIVersion",
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 1,
        "micro": 0
    }
}
```

where you specify API version

**2. login operation:**

POST request to `http://delphix-server/resources/json/delphix/login` with JSON data:

```
{
    "type": "LoginRequest",
    "username": "delphix_username",
    "password": "delphix_password"
}
```

also your client must support cookies (for store auth session)

Comment: so we no need to execute the curl command.We can user URL from cURL command and proceed to write a client for Delphix?

Comment: yes, curl just example, your client implements just what curl doing

Comment: thanks Evgeny Lebedev.So I need to send the json data to Delphix service from my RESTful client.Is it ?

Comment: yes with post\get (as API requires) and with cookies support